# ionic build failed because of Angular version

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to build `pwa`. so running `ng add @angular/pwa` first which worked fine.

But `ionic build --prod` fails with following

```
$ app# ionic build --prod --verbose
  ionic:lib Terminal info: { ci: false, shell: '/bin/bash', tty: true, windows: false } +0ms
  ionic:lib CLI global options: { _: [ 'build' ], help: null, h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json: null, prod: true, project: null, '--': [] } +6ms
  ionic:lib:project Project type from config: @ionic/angular (angular) +0ms
  ionic:lib:project Project details: { context: 'app', type: 'angular', errors: [], configPath: '/doctor-app/ionic.config.json' } +1ms
  ionic Context: { binPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/bin/ionic', libPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli', execPath: '/doctor-app', version: '6.12.3' } +0ms
  ionic:lib:build build options: { '--': [],
  ionic:lib:build   engine: 'browser',
  ionic:lib:build   platform: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   project: 'app',
  ionic:lib:build   verbose: true,
  ionic:lib:build   configuration: 'production',
  ionic:lib:build   sourcemaps: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   cordovaAssets: true,
  ionic:lib:build   watch: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   type: 'angular' } +0ms
  ionic:lib:telemetry Sending telemetry for command: 'ionic build' [ '--prod', '--verbose', '--interactive', '--color' ] +0ms
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
  ionic:lib:build Looking for ionic:build npm script. +26ms
> ng run app:build:production --verbose
  ng:analytics getGlobalAnalytics +0ms
  ng:analytics Client Analytics config found: "ea8c9b1d-f1d3-43d8-ad1c-7d1e8b3f92ea" +7ms
  ng:analytics client id: "ea8c9b1d-f1d3-43d8-ad1c-7d1e8b3f92ea" +1ms
  ng:analytics getWorkspaceAnalytics +10ms
  ng:analytics Workspace Analytics config found: false +0ms
  ng:analytics Analytics disabled. Ignoring all analytics. +0ms
  ng:analytics getSharedAnalytics +1ms
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions 0.0.0 || ^11.0.0-beta || >=11.0.0 <12.0.0,
but Angular version 9.1.13 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://update.angular.io/

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

        ng run app:build:production --verbose exited with exit code 3.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 functions +0ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 3) +14ms
```

What i am missing here ?

Package Info

```
app# ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.2.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.11
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.11
   @angular/cli                  : 11.0.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : not installed
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v10.19.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.4
   OS     : Linux 4.19
   
$ app# node -v
v10.19.0
$ app# npm -v
6.14.4
$ app# ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 11.0.5
Node: 10.19.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 9.1.13
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.901.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.901.11
@angular-devkit/core            9.1.11
@angular-devkit/schematics      9.1.11
@angular/cli                    11.0.5
@schematics/angular             9.1.11
@schematics/update              0.1100.5
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      3.8.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to install some packages to get this working.

```
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova native-run cordova-res
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the current angular cli:

```sh
npm uninstall @angular/cli
```

Install angular cli in its version 10.2.1:

```sh
npm install @angular/cli@10.2.1 --save-dev
```